# How to compare two arrays containing points to finding out the percentage of similarity?

Tags: arrays, comparison, classification, cluster-analysis, scoring

Suppose we've 10 arrays like below sample

[image: Sample array]

Every element of those array has two parts: the section number, time the cursor was there in second(for e.g in 3rd and 10th seconds cursor was in that section)

By the way, if they give the new array; we need to compare new one with our model and then show the similarity percentage for them to score the actions.
I really have no idea should I use any clustering or classification methods and if yes how it should be for arrays(we always learned about element of an array or some vectors in university)

Answer (score 0):

I found something in Jiawei Han, Micheline Kamber, Jian Pei Data mining book. what do you think about Cosine similarity?
but we need to convert that array to another including Section numbers and Frequency of refers.

[converted array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDEJG.png)